# C++ File Browser Error

Tags: c++, file, console, ifstream, file-browser

I am trying to make a basic file browser in C++, however it does not work very well.  I have put an image at the bottom to show what is happening as it is quite hard to explain:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#define NULL(str) (str == "")

using namespace std;

void read(string *memory);
void write(string *memory);

int main(void){
    string memory;
    for(;;){
        cout << "Please select your option:" << endl << "1: read a file - this text will be stored in memory until another file is read" << endl << "2: write text to a file - use ~MEM to get memory" << endl;
        char opt = getchar();
        switch(opt){
        case '1':
            read(&memory);
            break;
        case '2':
            write(&memory);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "The option was unrecongized" << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void read(string *memory){
    string path;
    cout << "Please enter the path of the file you would like to read" << endl;
    getline(cin, path);
    string str;
    string input;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(path);
    if(!file.is_open() || !file.good()){
        cout << "An error occured while reading the file" << endl << endl;
    }
    else{
        while(getline(file, str)){
            input += str;
        }
        file.close();
        if(NULL(input)){
            cout << "The input from the file is empty" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if(input.size() > 1000){
            cout << "The file is too large: it is bigger than 1000 characters" << endl << endl;
        }
        else{
            *memory = input;
            cout << input << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

void write(string *memory){
    string path;
    cout << "Please enter the path of the file you would like to write to" << endl;
    getline(cin, path);
    ofstream file;
    file.open(path);
    if(!file.is_open() || !file.good()){
        cout << "The file could not be written to" << endl << endl;
    }
    else{
        string input;
        getline(cin, input);
        if(input == "~MEM"){
            file << *memory;
        }
        else{
            file << input;
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

[image: My Problem]

Comment: You could at least make an attempt to explain the problem

Comment: Why do you pass pointers? Why not properly return objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're making the common mistake of not watching for line endings when reading user input.

If the user puts in `1` what's really in the input buffer is `1\n` (they had to push enter, right?) and you call `getchar` to get the `1` so the buffer now contains `\n`. Then when you call `getline` to get the path, it's going to read until the first new line. So it gets an empty string.

After your `getchar` you should call `ignore` to skip over the newline.